# C#: TCP Socket Framing causes method to never end?

Tags: c#, networking

I'm trying to implement length prefix based message framing. The issue is, I'm messing up somewhere.

Firstly the initial message is `1816339067` bytes, about 1.8 GB in size which seems extremely large, and the `ReceiveAsync()` method never actually ends.

Here is how I'm reading data:

```
public async Task StartListeningAsync()
{
    while (_client.Connected)
    {
        var dataReceived = await ReceiveAsync();
        var message = Encoding.Default.GetString(dataReceived);

        if (message == "PING")
        {
            LastPing = DateTime.Now;
            await WriteAsync(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("PONG"));
        }
    }
}

public async Task<byte[]> ReceiveAsync()
{
    var lengthPrefixBytes = new byte[sizeof(int)];
    
    try
    {
        await _client.GetStream().ReadExactlyAsync(lengthPrefixBytes);
    }
    catch (EndOfStreamException)
    {
        return Array.Empty<byte>();
    }
    
    var messageLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(lengthPrefixBytes);

    if (messageLength == 0)
    {
        return Array.Empty<byte>();
    }

    var buffer = new byte[messageLength];
    await _client.GetStream().ReadExactlyAsync(buffer);
    
    return buffer;
}
```

On send I am wrapping the bytes in my utility method:

```
public class FramingProtocol
{
    public static byte[] WrapMessage(byte[] message)
    {
        var lengthPrefix = BitConverter.GetBytes(message.Length);
        var all = new byte[lengthPrefix.Length + message.Length];

        lengthPrefix.CopyTo(all, 0);
        message.CopyTo(all, lengthPrefix.Length);

        return all;
    }
}
```

Comment: That a lot of bytes and it will take a lot of time and many man tcpip packages, so Ch communication should be done asnyronous

Comment: Possibly the bit endianness is different between the two machines? Are they both x86 CPU and both the same operating system? Side note: your `WrapMessage` function is unnecessarily inefficient. You can just `Write` the message length, then `Write` the message. No need to copy into a new array.